# Grayscale image becomes monochrome when using BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

i need to write a program which takes an image, resizes and rotates it and then saves it out. The first 2 point are done, but now I have a problem. Every time I convert a grayscale image it becomes a monochrome image.
I load the target image with the following command:

```
BufferedImage sourceimg = ImageIO.read(input);
```

And after I scaled and rotated it I save it out with the following command:

```
BufferedImage newimg = new BufferedImage(sourceimg.getHeight(), sourceimg.getWidth(), sourceimg.getType());
op.filter(sourceimg, newimg);

sourceimg = newimg;
ImageIO.write(sourceimg, "png", outputFile);
```

This works fine for every image except grayscale images. I have already tried a workaround by setting the type of every image to ARGB but there has to be another way. Is there a way to get the IndexColorModel of an given image?

Comment: what is `monochrome image`??

Comment: "Is there a way to get the IndexColorModel of an given image?" whats this have to do with your main question?? are you going for some complicated stuff to solve a simple pronblem?? also what's your deal with sourceimg=newimg ?

Comment: sourceimg=newimg is used because in a code that follows later it is used and the part where newimg get instanciated is optional and so i have no guarantee that newimg exists thats why sourceimg=newimg, the problem itself is solved with replacing 'sourceimg.getType()' with 'sourceimg.getColorModel().getNumColorComponents()'. I wanted to know if i can get the IndexColorModel because i thought i could maybe solve my problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ist now solved, i just had to change:

```
BufferedImage newimg = new BufferedImage(sourceimg.getHeight(), sourceimg.getWidth(), sourceimg.getType());
```

to:

```
BufferedImage newimg = new BufferedImage(sourceimg.getWidth(), sourceimg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Comment: Looking at the [constructor of `BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage-int-int-int-), I can say that this solution is bogus and only happens to work by coincidence. What is `sourceimg.getColorModel().getNumColorComponents()` in your case?

Comment: It returns the value 3

Comment: If i look up the constructor, it only uses the same colormodel for all the outputted images and thats why it works.

Comment: The value of 3 corresponds to `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE` . You likely could also use the widely used "default" type, namely `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Comment: Thanks, i have already changed it after i saw that it returns 3. I will also change it in the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

There are other solutions, especially if you like to keep the original image type (ie. keep palette of `IndexColorModel` images etc.).

In fact, the easiest is to just do (assuming `op` is a standard `BufferedImageOp`):

```
BufferedImage newimg = op.filter(sourceimg, null);
```

Here a new, compatible image will be created for you, and will be of correct size to keep the result of the operation.

Another option, which will preserve the image type and color model, is slightly more verbose:

```
ColorModel sourceCM = sourceimg.getColorModel(); // Will be the IndexColorModel in your case
// I'm assuming you are deliberately switching width/height to rotate 90 deg
WritableRaster raster = sourceCM.createCompatibleWritableRaster(sourceimg.getHeight(), sourceimg.getWidth());
BufferedImage newimg = new BufferedImage(sourceCM, raster, sourceCM.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);

op.filter(sourceimg, newimg);
```